# Select elements from a list of list where the elements of the sublists meet a criteria

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say that I have the following list

```
data = {{-41.10000000000002`, 2.873303230466569`, 
    6.310063685614807`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 2.873303230466569`, 
    5.839065774185954`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 19.236823144577595`, 
    11.735697959768771`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 19.236823144577595`, 
    12.10072134112616`}, {-31.340000000000032`, 11.842619292783251`, 
    20.776241204139154`}, {-31.340000000000032`, 11.842619292783251`, 
    20.78670782439312`}, {-21.590000000000032`, 4.449371441148591`, 
    19.155223392304862`}, {-21.590000000000032`, 4.449371441148591`, 
    19.363247469852638`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 35.60127021988911`, 
    3.921057612645157`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 35.60127021988911`, 
    9.843856348862907`}};
```

I would like to select the sublists with the same first and second element. For all sublist that meet this first criteria, select the maximum third element. For example for the given list, the solution will be:

```
{{-41.10000000000002`, 2.873303230466569`, 
  6.310063685614807`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 19.236823144577595`, 
  12.10072134112616`}, {-31.340000000000032`, 11.842619292783251`, 
  20.78670782439312`}, {-21.590000000000032`, 4.449371441148591`, 
  19.363247469852638`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 35.60127021988911`, 
  9.843856348862907`}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Last /@ (SortBy[#, Last] & /@ GatherBy[data, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &])
```

> ```
> {{-41.1, 2.8733, 6.31006}, {-41.1, 19.2368, 12.1007}, {-31.34, 
>   11.8426, 20.7867}, {-21.59, 4.44937, 19.3632}, {-41.1, 35.6013, 
>   9.84386}}
> ```

Comment: Very nice. Unfortunately I have to wait until I can vote again. Just a quick comment. Someone left a comment under my answer that was meant for yours. You can replace the [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) by `GatherBy[data, Most]`

Answer (score 7):

```
Values @ GroupBy[data, Most, First @* MaximalBy[Last]]
```

> ```
> {{-41.1, 2.8733, 6.31006},
>  {-41.1, 19.2368, 12.1007}, 
>  {-31.34, 11.8426, 20.7867}, 
>  {-21.59, 4.44937, 19.3632},
>  {-41.1, 35.6013, 9.84386}}
> ```

Comment: It's gonna be a (+1) from once I get to vote again. I just wanted to say that looking at your solution, I feel stupid. And more importantly, every time I see you wrote an answer I bring [`this`](https://media.makeameme.org/created/who-da-boss-5c27695736.jpg) in mind. (I hope you are not offended, I meant it as a good-hearted joke :-) )

Comment: thank you @bmf :)

Answer (score 5):

---

### **Data from the OP**

---

```
data = {
   {-41.10000000000002`, 2.873303230466569`, 
    6.310063685614807`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 2.873303230466569`, 
    5.839065774185954`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 19.236823144577595`, 
    11.735697959768771`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 19.236823144577595`, 
    12.10072134112616`}, {-31.340000000000032`, 11.842619292783251`, 
    20.776241204139154`}, {-31.340000000000032`, 11.842619292783251`, 
    20.78670782439312`}, {-21.590000000000032`, 4.449371441148591`, 
    19.155223392304862`}, {-21.590000000000032`, 4.449371441148591`, 
    19.363247469852638`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 35.60127021988911`, 
    3.921057612645157`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 35.60127021988911`, 
    9.843856348862907`}
   };
```

The desired output as shown in the OP

```
opoutput = {
   {-41.10000000000002`, 2.873303230466569`, 
    6.310063685614807`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 19.236823144577595`, 
    12.10072134112616`}, {-31.340000000000032`, 11.842619292783251`, 
    20.78670782439312`}, {-21.590000000000032`, 4.449371441148591`, 
    19.363247469852638`}, {-41.10000000000002`, 35.60127021988911`, 
    9.843856348862907`}
   };
```

---

### **Proposed solution:**

---

```
ArrayReshape[
 Table[Reverse /@ 
       Take[#, Ordering[#, -1]] &@(Reverse /@ #) &@{data[[xx]], 
    data[[xx + 1]]}, {xx, 1, Length@data, 2}], {Length@data/2, 3}]
```

---

### **Testing the proposed solution:**

---

```
ArrayReshape[
  Table[Reverse /@ 
        Take[#, Ordering[#, -1]] &@(Reverse /@ #) &@{data[[xx]], 
     data[[xx + 1]]}, {xx, 1, Length@data, 2}], {Length@data/2, 
   3}] - opoutput
```

> `{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}}`